# How to passing function overload set as template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, template-meta-programming

I have code like this:

```cpp
template<auto Function>
struct Bind
{
    template<typename... Args>
    static auto func(Args&&... args)
    {
        return std::invoke(Function, args...);
    }
};

struct F
{
    int i;
    auto foo(int ii){ i = ii; }
};

int main()
{
    F f{};
    Bind<&F::foo>::func(f, 5); //set `i` to 5
    return Bind<&F::i>::func(f); //return 5
}
```

But now I need add new function `int F::foo();` and I still need be able to call both from `func`, like:

```cpp
template<typename TBind>
auto bar(F f)
{
    TBind::func(f, 5); // calls `void F::foo(int)`
    return TBind::func(f); // calls `int F::foo()`
}
```

Is possible to do it in C++17 and still use `auto Function`?

(C++20 can have custom types as value template argument that solve this problem)

Answer (score 0):

C++17 can't pass custom objects as template parameters but allow pass pointers to it.

With small helper function we can easy do it:

```cpp
#include <functional>

//this will dereferece all arguments in form of `T*` or return it without change
template<typename T>
auto optDeref(T t) { return t; }
template<typename T>
auto optDeref(T* t) -> T& { return *t; }

template<auto Function>
struct Bind
{
    template<typename... Args>
    static auto func(Args&&... args)
    {
        return std::invoke(optDeref(Function), std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
};

struct F
{
    int i;
    void foo(int ii){ i = ii; }
    int foo() { return i; }
};

template<typename TBind>
int bar(F f)
{
    TBind::func(f, 5);
    return TBind::func(f);
}

struct
{
    template<typename... Args>
    auto operator()(F& f, Args&&... args) const -> decltype(auto) { return f.foo(args...); }
} f_overload;

struct
{
    auto operator()(F& f) const { return f.foo(); }
    auto operator()(F& f, int i) const { return f.foo(i); }
} f_overloadLimited;

int main()
{
    F f{};
    return Bind<&F::i>::func(f) + bar<Bind<&f_overload>>(f) + bar<Bind<&f_overloadLimited>>(f);
}
```

Working example:

https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/HMuxN_ (gotbolt have some problems with VS right now (2020-04-24) and do not show success correctly for it)